# How do I determine the date of a file on the local windows machine, prior to uploading (with php)?

Tags: php

When I upload a file with PHP, I want to know the date of the original file.

when I use filectime:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", filectime($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']))
```

I get the today's date (date the file on my sever is created).

How do I get the date of the *original* file stored on the user's computer?

Comment: you will need to use `flash` to get the file information from the end users computer http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Comment: you can use the html5 file api to get the file information on client side and send it to php with your upload form.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. PHP can only date files that it has file system access to. Since you get the data from a network socket, there is no file to date until your server actually makes one, and then writes the socket-received data into it.

You can make the client responsible for recording the file's "true" date and then send that along as part of the POST operation ([HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), using Flash, asking the user to input it, etc) but then you'll have to simply extract that data from `$_POST`, it won't be a property of the file data that gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP/server side you can't as this information is not transfered by the client / browser doing the file upload.

With HTML5 it seems to be possible to access lastModification date attribute on the client side using the HTML5 File API. If you have an input filed like:

```
<input type='file' name='foo'/>
```

you should be able to access it like this (untested):

```
var files = document.getElementById('foo').files;
var file = files[0];
var filedate = file.lastModifiedDate;
```

and then store the `filedate` in an extra hidden input field before form transmission (again: untested).

See also:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Use `filectime.` For Windows it will return  the time the file was last changed, and for Unix the change time which is the best you can get because on Unix there is no creation time (in most filesystems).
Unfortunately if you are running on linux you cannot access the information as only the last modified date is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `filemtime`. I hope that the example below will help you.

```
echo "Last modified: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime("test.txt"));
```

Last modified time will be when its created. On failure this function will returns false.

See also:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filemtime.asp